# Use Calendar within emulator Android 4.0 +

Tags: android, events, android-emulator, calendar, account

I'm playing around with the calendar API of ICS but can't test it on the emulator. I have configured a new virtual device with Google Inc SDK 14 as target. I've added my gmail account in Settings/Account.

**I can see my emails, and within the Calendar app, in Menu/Settings, I can see my gmail account.**

But, in my app when I launch the calendar intent,

I see this message:

**"No calendars, Before you can add an event, you must add at least one Calendar account to the device and make calendar visible. [...]"**

So I went in the aCalendar app, went to Menu/Calendar to Display and here, I can't see anything.

I'm not an Android expert, what am I missing ?
Cheers