# Android Emulator: Calendar application will not synchronize with google calendar

Tags: android, android-emulator, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I would like to reopen this question since I am having the same problem:

[Use Calendar within emulator Android 4.0 +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070717/use-calendar-within-emulator-adroid-4-0)

Namely, I see a Calendar application on virtual devices running android 4.0
or later (there is no calendar application on android 3.2 even though my physical
gingerbread phone has once such an app, which I find strange). However I am not
able to synchronize the data on the android 4.0 or later emulator with my google
account's calendar data. Here are the details:

---

I had created an Android 4.2.2 emulator and launched the calendar application
from within such an emulator. I want to sync my google account with the calendar
application. So I hit menu -> Settings -> ADD ACCOUNT. Nothing happens. So I tried
to hit menu -> Calendars to display ->  Calendars to sync, but the list is empty
and hitting menu does not bring up a menu.

I suspected the problem was I needed google apis to work. So I created a new
4.2.2 virtual device with google apis. When I launched such emulator and then the
calendar application I got a screen saying "Make it Google", "Do you want to add
an existing account or create a new one?". Click on Existing. I entered my
sign in details. I click on the popup asking me to agree to google terms
of service, and I accepted. It then says "Signing in..." "This can take a few minutes."
The Backup and Restore screen shows up and I click forward and proceed. However I
do not see the contents of my google calendar's account on the android calendar.

When I launch the calendar application again it asks me once again to
"Make it Google" and enter my account information. If I enter the old
information it complains telling me I have already specified such an
account. However my google account's data does not show up in android calendar.

I cannot understand why or what I am doing wrong.

(Alas I do not have a 4.0+ phone to test with so I am stuck having to get
the emulator to work).

Thanks for your feedback,

Jason Posit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use and test the Android 4.0 Calendar API in the emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959847/how-to-use-and-test-the-android-4-0-calendar-api-in-the-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is older, but I did find a solution. I was never able to get a Google account to work since Google blocks active sync on free accounts.

The solution for me was to signup for a free outlook.com account and use outlook.com's active sync settings.

The steps I followed are from [my blog](http://samuelhaddad.com/2015/06/16/add-a-calendar-on-android-emulator/) and are as follows:

- Sign out for free account at outlook.com
- Select a Corporate Account
- Enter username such as email@outlook.com
- Select Manual Setup
- Select account type of “Exchange” (This will allow us to sync with active
  sync)
- Enter Server as s.outlook.com
- Security type as SSL/TLS
- Select next
- Confirm settings.

Answer (score 0):

As "Corporate Account" type isn't being provided in newer emulator images, one can install custom CalDAV adapter, which amusingly does work with Google's CalDAV interface.